# Como hago para que la función reinicio se vuelva a aparecer cuando termine mi operación

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentado que el código def reinicio(self), se vuelva a aparecer cuando termine mi operación, pero no aparece nuevamente. Ya intente con while, cuentaBancaria.inicio(self) y cuentaBancaria.inicio() y no me aparece nuevamente al terminar mi operación. Acá dejo el código:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
  def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
    self.titular = titular
    self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
    self.saldo = saldo

  def inicio(self):
    inicios = input("¿Que tramite quiere realizar?: ")
    if inicios == "ingreso":
     mensaje = cuentaBancaria.ingresos(self)
     return mensaje
    elif inicios == "retirar":
      mensaje = cuentaBancaria.retiros(self)
      return mensaje
    elif inicios == "saldo":
      mensaje = cuentaBancaria.saldos(self)
      return mensaje 
    else:
      error = ("Esta opcion no es validad")
      return error
    
  def ingresos(self):
    ingreso = int(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))
    aumento2 = self.saldo + ingreso
    aumentos = (f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {aumento2}")
    return aumentos

  def retiros(self):
    retiro = int(input("Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?: "))
    if retiro > self.saldo:
      disminucion =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
      return disminucion
    else:
      disminucion2 = self.saldo - retiro
      disminucion = (f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {disminucion2}")
      return disminucion  
  
  def saldos(self):
    saldo_actual = self.saldo
    return saldo_actual
  
  def reinicio(self):
    reinicios = cuentaBancaria.inicio(self)
    return reinicios

mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
print(mi_sueldo.reinicio())
```

Además ya intente con raw_input pero tampoco me funciono, acá dejo como me imprime.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Tu código tiene algunos errores de concepto.

En primer lugar, al utilizar los métodos de tu clase (Funciones internas de la clase `cuentaBancaria`) dentro de la misma clase, se debe hacer de la siguiente forma:

```
self.<El método que se va a utilizar>(<Argumentos>)
```

Por ejemplo:

```
self.saldo()
```

De otra forma lo que haces es acceder a una nueva instancia.

Ahora, si lo que pretendes hacer es que el menú se repita una y otra vez hasta que el usuario no quiera más, entonces puedes utilizar un ciclo infinito para preguntarle al usuario lo que desea hacer una y otra vez hasta que diga que desea terminar la operación.

Para esto puedes utilizar `while True:` y agregar una condición, por ejemplo, si el usuario escribiera "fin" entonces interrumpir ese ciclo infinito con `break`.

**Nota:** Cuando evaluas entradas del usuario existen muchas combinaciones de mayúsculas y minúsculas, por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresa "Saldo" sería diferente de "saldo" y de "SALDO", mas todas las posibles combinaciones, para poder cubrir todos esos escenarios lo que puedes hacer es utilizar `lower()` que converirá lo ingresado por el usuario en minúsculas y entonces evaluar siempre con minúsculas.

Otro consejo, por lo general se recomienda que los métodos únicamente cumplan con su función y que los valores se pasen como argumentos, por ejemplo en tu método ingreso sería mejor que tuvieras un argumento `cantidad` y que el método únicamente se dedique a sumar la cantidad:

```
def ingresos(self, cantidad):
    self.saldo += cantidad
    return f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"
```

**Nota adicional:** Puedes utilizar los operadores `+=` y `-=` para "ahorrarte" un poco de escritura, en el caso de `self.saldo += cantidad` esto es equivalente a poner `self.saldo = self.saldo + cantidad`.

Y deberíamos obtener esa `cantidad` en el menú.

Ejemplo completo aplicando los comentarios anteriores:

```
class cuentaBancaria:
    def __init__(self, titular, numero_de_cuenta, saldo):
        self.titular = titular
        self.numero_de_cuenta = numero_de_cuenta
        self.saldo = saldo

    def inicio(self):
        # Ciclo infinito que únicamente se interrumpe al ingresar "fin"
        while True:
            inicios = input("¿Que tramite quiere realizar?: ").lower()
            if inicios == "ingreso":
                ingreso = int(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))
                mensaje = self.ingresos(ingreso)
            elif inicios == "retirar":
                retiro = int(input("Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?: "))
                mensaje = self.retiros(retiro)
            elif inicios == "saldo":
                mensaje = self.saldos()
            # Condición para terminar el ciclo infinito
            elif inicios == "fin":
                # Finaliza el ciclo while
                break
            else:
                mensaje = "Esta opcion no es validad"
                
            # Mostramos el mensaje obtenido de los métodos de la clase
            print(mensaje)
        return "Gracias por su visita"

    def ingresos(self, cantidad):
        self.saldo += cantidad
        return f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"

    def retiros(self, cantidad):
        if cantidad > self.saldo:
            mensaje =  "Ud no cuenta con el saldo suficiente"
        else:
            self.saldo -= cantidad
            mensaje = f"Tu saldo es ahora de: {self.saldo}"
        return mensaje

    def saldos(self):
        return f"Tu saldo es: {self.saldo}"


mi_sueldo = cuentaBancaria("Juan", 199733051214, 1000)
print(mi_sueldo.inicio())
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento (Nota como se puede combinar mayúsculas con minúsculas):

```
¿Que tramite quiere realizar?:  IngReso
¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?:  80
Tu saldo es ahora de: 1080
¿Que tramite quiere realizar?:  RetirAr
Cuanto dinero quieres retirar?:  150
Tu saldo es ahora de: 930
¿Que tramite quiere realizar?:  SALDO
Tu saldo es: 930
¿Que tramite quiere realizar?:  Ayuda
Esta opcion no es validad
¿Que tramite quiere realizar?:  fin
Gracias por su visita
```

**Nota extra:** En tu código estás utilizando números enteros, yo te recomendaría cambiarlo por flotantes, por ejemplo `float(input("¿Cuanto quiere ingresar de dinero?: "))` para que puedas trabaar con decimales.

Comment: Hay otras cosas que estuve pensando que tu código debería cubrir, por ejemplo, ¿Qué sucede si el usuario desea retirar una cantidad negativa? Tal como está ahora sería igual que un ingreso por lo que tu código debería prevenir ese tipo de "fallas".